# Insert clob data or all types of file store in database

Tags: java, javascript

I try to save All types of file in database , I try to save it in nclob  in java 
but I got following exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNClob(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
File fileIn = new File("OracleClobSetCharacterStream.java");
ps.setCharacterStream(1, bodyIn, (int) fileIn.length());
```

this worked for me once. Hope this solves your problem.